# Select rows between two dates and send mail with some context using python

Tags: python

I have a csv file with below data as an example. I wanted to filter rows between specific date range(last use column with start:2000-01-01 to end:2018-08-28) and all N/A as well. and loop through each filtered line while grep for email id and send mail with some text appended to the user.

```
NUMBER,MAIL,TEXT1,TEXT2,TEXT3,TEXT4,COMMENT,COUNT,LAST USE,PERCENTAGE,TEXTN
343,user1@example.com,"Some text1","Some text2",text3,text4,"My comment","21577",2018-08-06,80.436%,
222,user2@example.com,"Some text1","Some text2",text3,text4,"My comment","31181",2018-07-20,11.858%,
103,user3@example.com,"Some text1","Some text2",text3,text4,"My comment",540,2018-06-14,2.013%,
341,user4@example.com,"Some text1","Some text2",text3,text4,"My comment",0,N/A,0.000%,
```

Any idea to write a better python script?

Tried below format but result was not satisfying. I am very much new to python. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#! python3
import csv,time,sys,datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", index_col=8, parse_dates=True)
df.query("'2000-01-01' <= index <= '2018-08-30'")
print(df.query)
```

Output i am getting:

```
# python my_file.py
<bound method DataFrame.query of             NUMBER                          
MAIL      ...      PERCENTAGE TEXTN
LAST USE                                            ...
2018-08-06   343  user1@example.com      ...         80.436%           NaN
2018-07-20   222  user2@example.com      ...         11.858%           NaN
2018-06-14   103  user3@example.com      ...          2.013%           NaN
NaT          341  user4@example.com      ...          0.000%           NaN
```

Looking for output like this:

First redirect output to some_result.csv

```
343 user1@example.com   2018-08-06
222 user2@example.com   2018-07-20
103 user3@example.com   2018-06-14
341 user4@example.com   N/A
```

then grep for each line, and email to id stored in column 2

Answer (score 0):

When I try out the code with the input provided, data is not parsed into the dataframe correctly.

Just try to print the first column in your dataframe,

```
print(df.iloc[:,0])
```

It hasn't been separated with the ",", whereas it should have been just the number value. And df.query doesn't really work, just printing the df again.

How to fix it? You're using different quotes in your data. Correct the input data as below (referencing just the first row)

```
NUMBER,MAIL,TEXT1,TEXT2,TEXT3,TEXT4,COMMENT,COUNT,LAST USE,PERCENTAGE,TEXTN
343,user1@example.com,Some text1,Some text2,text3,text4,My comment,21577,2018-08-06,80.436%,
```

Either put the strings/dates in quotes or don't use any quotes at all.

If you can have the dataframe with data separated properly, rest will be easy. I'll update with the relevant code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: print(df.iloc[:,0]) helps but the main issue i noticed is the date range filter not working properly here.

    df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", index_col=8, parse_dates=True)
    df.query("'2018-07-20' <= index <= '2018-08-20'")
    print(df.query)

    LAST USE
    2018-08-06   user1@example.com   
    2018-07-20   user2@example.com   
    2018-06-14   user3@example.com   
    NaN              user4@example.com 
    Name: NAME, dtype: object

Comment: It is not working since the data is not read properly. The format of the source data is problematic, please read my previous comments and try to reformat the data in the cvs file. Could you then repost the re-formatted data?